# Am facing this problem while saving the file as .mlmodel from h5 type

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, coremltools

I'm working on a handwriting app using the Tensorflow library and Keras and coremltools library so after first I saved my model as an h5 file, I'm trying to convert the file from h5 type to mlmodel, which gives me an error like that:

```
1875/1875 [==============================] - 38s 19ms/step - loss: 2.2083 - accuracy: 0.2727 - val_loss: 2.0820 - val_accuracy: 0.4546
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\Py files\handwriting app.py", line 78, in <module>
    mlmodel = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(keras_model)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'coremltools.converters' has no attribute 'keras'.
```

Here's what I have got so far, but I'm getting the same error:

```
import keras 
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Dense, Dropout, Flatten
import coremltools

pixel_width = 28
pixel_height = 28
batch_size = 32
epochs = 1

num_of_classes  = 10

(features_train, labels_train), (features_test, labels_test) = mnist.load_data()

features_train = features_train.reshape(features_train.shape[0], pixel_width, pixel_height, 1)
features_test = features_test.reshape(features_test.shape[0], pixel_width, pixel_height, 1)

input_shape = (pixel_width, pixel_height, 1)

features_train = features_train.astype('float32')
features_test = features_test.astype('float32')

features_train /= 255
features_test /= 255

labels_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(labels_train, num_of_classes)
labels_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(labels_test, num_of_classes)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
# print("Post Conv2D:", Model.output_shape)
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_of_classes, activation='softmax'))
# print("Post Maxpooling2D:", Model.output_shape)
model.compile(loss = keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer= keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=(['accuracy'])
              )

model.fit(features_train, labels_train,
          batch_size= batch_size,
          epochs= epochs,
          verbose= 1,
          validation_data=(features_test, labels_test))

score = model.evaluate(features_test, labels_test, verbose=0)
model.save('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\work.h5')


coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(model, input_names= ['image'],
                                                    image_input_names= 'image')
```

Comment: Try with `import coremltools.converters.keras` instead of `import coremltools`.

Comment: I tried it before and still have the same error., still telling me that there is no attribute called Keras.